# Semper Sol / Semper Novo

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

this is the first time I post in any forum but better late than ever!
I'm looking for a cool Latin name which I can use for my new personal Trust which my accountant is setting up soon. I've come up with two different names to pick from, Semper Sol and Semper Novo (or Semper Novus). I know the meaning of each individual word but I'm wondering if someone could tell me if they make sense once you join them together. I was hoping Semper Sol would come across as meaning the Sun is always shining / Always shining, while Semper Novo would mean Always Anew! Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you looking to keep it specific to just two words?

Comment: Thanks Adam. Doesn't have to be specific but I'd prefer to keep it at two words if I could as I don't want to have a lengthy Trust name. I'm just trying to find a cool sounding Latin name so it can sound original.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the site!

**Semper sol** means "always the sun," which for me immediately evoked the [Stranglers song of the same name](https://youtu.be/Um9kd-mhhK4) (but I may be showing my age here), but does in my opinion not really imply permanent shining. What could you say instead? I would suggest: **semper lucet** (it always shines) or **semper luceat** (may it always shine); that it is the sun (and not, say, the moon) would have to be guessed by the reader.

Alternatively, you could explicitly say "the sun always shines," e.g. **sol semper lucet**.

By the way, a famous expression is *sol omnibus lucet* -- originally from the Satyricon of Petronius, now occasionally found on sundials -- meaning "the sun shines for everyone," but that would presumably not be very apt for a trust fund ...

**Semper novo** does not really make sense; for "always anew, afresh" I would suggest **semper denuo**.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough feedback Sebastian. That is really helpful :)

Comment: +1 to the Stranglers reference.